# Solc_version="0.6.0" - compile_Standard isnt found

Tags: solidity, compiler

I have a problem with my code. I have seen similiar threats in this group and I have applied all of the steps unfortunately without any luck...

Could anyone pls help...:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc 
install_solc("0.6.0") 

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "solidity",
        "sources": {"simpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)



print("compiled_sol")
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSCode-win32-x64-1.40.1\Project\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 9, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  File "C:\UsersPython\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 394, in compile_standard
    raise SolcError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcError: Only "Solidity" or "Yul" is supported as a language.
> command: `C:\Users\.solcx\solc-v0.6.0\solc.exe --standard-json`
> return code: `0`
> stdout:
{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"Only \"Solidity\" or \"Yul\" is supported as a language.","message":"Only \"Solidity\" or \"Yul\" is supported as a language.","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]} 

> stderr:
```

I have installed the npm install -g solc aswell

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

Solidity needs to be written with capital "S"